# How to preload / cache a hidden view in android

Tags: android

So I have an activity whose layout contains a FrameLayout. This frame layout will be replaced with one of two fragments.

Fragment A will be shown on creation of the view, and there is a switch which when checked will switch to fragment B.

I am attempting to make the app as responsive as possible, however the first time the switch occurs there is a noticeable delay, probably due to rendering of the view, where as for subsequent switches the view is already cached or whatnot.

How do i go about getting fragment B view to render and cached while being hidden at the same time. Again this is for the initial switch, not subsequent ones so things like using hiding showing fragments instead of replace won't help.

Comment: Why are the question and answers all -1 without any comments? That's quite unfair.

Answer (score 1):

This effect can be achieved by specifying android:visibility to "invisible" in the XML layout file or in the code by View.setVisibility(VIEW.INVISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this wrong. **First** you need to find out what the culprit is, **then** optimize or fix. Profile your fragments' `onCreateView()` or other methods you are doing something in and find out what makes is crawl. Also be aware that devices vary, and your problem may ie be visible only on slowest devices available.

Here is [article for about profiling Android apps](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)